# how can i use useState when fetching an api in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I have a dashboard.js file which is supposed to render information about user from firebase database. I want to loop over this fetched data, find user which email matches my currentUser.email state (kinda not the best practice)
I dont know how to assign this found user to a state (it runs endlessly) so I can render entire dashboard so: first name, username, profile image.

[img: thats what i get in console, and want it accessible in entire scope](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrYXt.png)
So if you take a look at this screenshot i want my dashboard to look like **this**:
-email:newadmin@gmail.com
-name:Joe Black
- and profile picture

this is supossed to be a profile page so i will add bio and more things, i basically want this database to be fully accessible here based on **email** which i pass between components, users login via email

```
const Dashboard = () => {
    const [error, setError] = useState("");
    const { setcurrentUser, currentUser, logout, email } = useContext(UserProvider);
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const handleLogOut = async () => {
        setError("");
        try {
            await logout();
            navigate("/login");
        } catch (err) {
            setError(err);
        }
    };
    auth.onAuthStateChanged((currentUser) => {
        if (currentUser) {
            setcurrentUser(currentUser);
        }
    });

    const url = "https://skitter-9e5e3-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/users.json";
    const [emailstate, setEmailstate] = useState();

    const byEmail = async () => {
        const response = await fetch(url);
        const data = await response.json();
        for (let i = 0; i <= Object.keys(data).length; i++) {
            if (data[Object.keys(data)[i]].email == currentUser.email) {
                console.log(data[Object.keys(data)[i]]);
            }
        }
    };

    byEmail();

    return (
        <>
            <Card>
                <Card.Body>
                    <span className="text-center">
                        <strong>Email: {currentUser.email}</strong>
                    </span>
                </Card.Body>
            </Card>
            <div>
                <Button variant="link" onClick={handleLogOut}>
                    Log out
                </Button>
            </div>
        </>
    );
};

export default Dashboard;
```

Comment: It can be worthwhile to handle fetching outside of an effect. There are many state containers and related solutions that work well with React and as a side effect your component code becomes simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Use an effect hook so that the fetch request only runs once, rather than every time the component runs. You should do the same for the `onAuthStateChanged` - you only need to add one listener, not one listener for every time the component's been rendered.

When you find a matching item in the response, set it to a state variable. In a for loop, don't start with 0 and use `i <= arr.length` - that'll iterate once more than the length of the array. End at the last index of the array with `i < arr.length` instead - or avoid manual iteration entirely and use `find` instead.

```
const [userData, setUserData] = useState();
useEffect(() => {
    auth.onAuthStateChanged(setcurrentUser);
    const url = "https://skitter-9e5e3-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/users.json";
    fetch(url)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
            const currentUserObj = Object.values(data).find(obj => obj.email === currentUser?.email);
            if (currentUserObj) {
                setUserData(currentUserObj);
            }
        })
        .catch(handleErrors); // don't forget this part - don't ignore errors
}, []);
```

Then the `userData` state will contain the object from the API, if one was found.

Comment: I would put `onAuthStateChanged` to a different `useEffect` to avoid [one giant useEffect](https://epicreact.dev/myths-about-useeffect/).

Comment: That's an option if you prefer that style, but I don't think the additional code with no observable difference would be useful to get into here, given the problem OP is facing and how new they seem to be